# mysql Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'unique_id'

Tags: mysql

I create around 500000 unique keys in a mysql table.

The table is empty.
I have set the index to 1 `alter table my_table auto_increment = 1;`

The field `unique_id` is a `varchar` and `unique`.

When i start the script to create the keys i get the following error message.

for example

The key to write is `4947E4`

the message is `Duplicate entry '4947' for key 'unique_id'`

next

The key to write is `676E97`

the message is `Duplicate entry '676' for key 'unique_id'`

and so on. It looks like mysql picks out the integer values of the key and checks if they exists.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Please help

Comment: *Is it a bug or a feature?* [CTRL+F "banana"](http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else).

Comment: `4947E4`.... do you mean `49470000`?

Comment: can you show your create table query ?

Comment: @ta.speot.is interesting. But unconvertible at time :-)

Comment: @MarkBaker my script create strings and write this strings into a varchar field. why this should happen?

Comment: @echo_Me `CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  unique_id varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY unique_id (unique_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7354 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: And your insert statement for these values is binding them as a string value?

Comment: @MarkBaker this is sick question , he showed create with varchar , and finally he have integer column as i understood from his accepting answer.

Comment: In what way is it sick? I see your CREATE TABLE statement, but no SQL INSERT code; but if you try binding a string like `4947E4` as an integer, then it's possible that the binding would convert that value to an integer using standard PHP type conversion rules

Comment: @MarkBaker Right. the typecast makes 4947 from 4947E4.

Comment: @ninchen - That was my thought, so it's dependent on the actual code that you use to build and execute your INSERTs

Comment: @MarkBaker look at my answer. it was my mistake. but not a dump question.

Comment: the comment not the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the type of unique_id field, it behaves like it is an INTEGER.

Answer (score 1):

1- you have some trick on your query when using DEFAULT NULL . and then you say unique_id . so if you insert two values with the DEFAULT value the they will be both NULL and they are duplicates.

2- ou have to check if you insert the string 4947E4 .

3- Try using unique_id with id as id is autoincrement and will never duplicated.

```
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (id , unique_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know why, but it seems that php type functions are odd. I have commented out this part before the mysql statement gets fired. now it works

```
   `foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {

        if (is_string($value))
        {
            $data[$key] = self::$_db->real_escape_string($value);
        }
        if (is_numeric($value))
        {
            $data[$key] = (int)$value;
        }
    }`
```

`is_string` should be true because for example 676E97 is a string. Or not?